# Choosing the boxes were never difficult like this?

Tags: probability, solution-verification

A jar contains ten boxes (marked from 1 to 10). Four boxes are drawn without replacement, the number noted. Find the probability of:

a. Smallest number is 5?

b. Biggest number is 5?

So I have used this approach:

a) probability of getting a 5 would be 1/10 and other 3 boxes can be chosen by (5/9),(4/8),(3/7) ie (1*5*4*3)/(9*8*7*10) since greater than 5 we have 5 numbers including 10 ie 6,7,8,9,10 - 5 in total

b) Similarly if biggest number is 5 ie probability of 5 would be 1/10 then in total we have 4 numbers which are smaller than 5 and so probability would be  (1/10) * (4/9) * (3/8) * (2/7)

Not sure if choosing the right thing?

Answer (score 0):

The number of possible combinations is given by the formula $$\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$$

So $$\frac{10!}{4!(10-4)!} = 210$$

Now solving the first question.

There are 5 numbers greater than '5' in the selection but only 3 of them can be selected because there is already a '5' and we only need four. So solving for the combinations

$$\frac{5!}{3!(5-3)!} = 10$$

We can now conclude that the answer for 1 is
$$\frac{10}{210}$$ or $$\frac{1}{21}$$

For the second question we can do the same.

$$\frac{4!}{3!(4-3)!} = 4$$

Then conclude that the answer for question 2 is

$$\frac{4}{210}$$ or $$\frac{2}{105}$$

Note: Use MathJax so it won't get deleted. The tutorial link is here below.

[MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks, I got it now but didn't get meaning of this line

Note: Use MathJax so it won't get deleted. The tutorial link is here below.

What would be deleted?

Comment: @adm The post itself will be deleted. As you see there is a format used in writing equations here. Users prefer the mentioned format because it is easier to understand.